# SQL Rolling 3 months total with Yearmonth

Tags: sql

Hi i have a dataset which has accounts, yearmonth and trade count

```
account   Yearmonth   Trade_count
XXXXX       201701        1
XXXXX       201701        0
XXXXX       201702        1
XXXXX       201703        1
XXXXX       201704        1
XXXXX       201704        1
XXXXX       201705        1
```

The trade_count is 1 if the trade was processed and 0 if not processed

i want an output like this

```
Account  Yearmonth    Total_Trades_Month     past_3_month trades
XXXXX      201703           1                       3
XXXXX      201704           2                       3
XXXXX      201705           1                       4
```

So far i've tried:

```
select yearmonth, (yearmonth - 3) as 'ym',
 SUM(Case when COMMISSION is not null and Commission > 0 then Trade_Count Else 0 END) as 'TotalTrades',
 sum(CASE when yearmonth between (yearmonth - 3) and yearmonth and commission > 0 then Trade_Count else 0 end) as  'rolling'
 sum(Trade_Count)over(partition by yearmonth)
FROM WEALTHDB.DBO.WF_PM_DOR_DB 
group by  yearmonth
order by yearmonth
```

please note the yearmonth is just an integer and not coded as a date. Any help is appreciated

Comment: can there be missing months?

Comment: Which SQL are you using? Modern SQL has __window functions__ which is ideal for rolling totals. I assume that `Yearmonth` is your own device?

Comment: If `yearmonth` is an integer, don’t you have problems with comparing, say `201611+3` with `201701`?

Comment: if an account doesnt place a trade in a month then its missing. SQL server 2012 sql managment studio 2012

Answer (score 2):

If you have no months with missing data (as in your example data), you can do:

```
select account, yearmonth, 
       sum(trade_count) as TotalTrades,
       sum(sum(trade_count)) over (partition by account order by yearmonth
                                   rows between 2 preceding and current row
                                  ) as past_3_month_trades
from WEALTHDB.DBO.WF_PM_DOR_DB 
group by account, yearmonth
order by yearmonth
```